# Laravel 5.5 - Horizon not running second queue automatically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-horizon

Using Laravel Horizon on Forge with Redis, I have a `default` queue and a `notifications` queue.

The notification jobs are all built up with a pause status under recent jobs and do NOT get processed. This is the code used:

```
$event->owner->notify((new ItemWasLiked($event))->onQueue('notifications'));
```

The only way I found to process them was to manually run the following command explicitly for `notifications` to process:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=notifications
```

Shouldn't this be automatic as it comes in? What am I missing?

Comment: Is horizon [running](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/horizon#running-horizon)? You're supposed to set it up to run via something like supervisor.

Comment: It should be running automatically on forge when we add a daemon I believe, shows as running under daemon status in forge, I also ran it with `php artisan horizon` manually just in case, but still paused and not processing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to instruct Horizon to start a queue worker that processes the `notifications` queue in addition to the `default` queue by adding an element to the queue worker configuration in *config/horizon.php*:

```
'environments' => [
    ...
    '(environment name)' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            ...
            'queue' => [ 'default', 'notifications' ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

The `'queue'` directive declares which queues a Horizon worker watches for jobs. The out-of-box configuration only specifies the `default` queue, so the worker will only process jobs pushed to that queue. The above is roughly equivalent to:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=default,notifications
```

...where the first queue in the comma-separated list has the highest priority, and the last queue has the lowest priority. Horizon prioritizes queues by allocating a greater share of the number of processes rather than processing queues in order of priority.

Alternatively, we could add a second worker group to the configuration that processes the second queue:

```
'(environment name)' => [
    'supervisor-1' => [
        ...
        'queue' => [ 'default' ],
    ],
    'supervisor-2' => [
        ...
        'queue' => [ 'notifications' ],
    ],
],
```

...for which Horizon starts queue worker processes for each each of the two queues that run simultaneously.

Comment: You're a life saver! I spent all day yesterday trying to figure this out. So I had all the queues setup correctly in `horizon.php` EXCEPT for the '(environment name)' as mine was `development`, instead of the default `production`/`local`. So I added a `development` block to horizon with the queues and it worked perfectly. Thanks again you made my day!

Comment: @Wonka Good catch...can't say that I really answered your question directly, but I'm glad you figured it out!